# How to commit changes to repository but not submodule

Tags: git, git-submodules, pelican

I am working on making a blog using [pelican](http://docs.getpelican.com/en/3.3.0/). I want to include the existing [pelican-plugins](https://github.com/getpelican/pelican-plugins) in my project without copying the code into my repository. For example:

```
/my_project
    pelicanconf.py
    /plugins        # Just a reference to https://github.com/getpelican/pelican-plugins
        assets
        ...
```

I know that this is possible via `git submodule` as follows:

```
git submodule add https://github.com/getpelican/pelican-plugins.git plugins
```

However, should I decide to create my own plugins, or user plugins from elsewhere, I can't store them in `plugins` because that's now a submodule.

*How can I commit changes to a folder that is a submodule without committing them to that submodule?* Should I just be making a fork of `pelican-plugins` and commit to that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution that worked for me in this case was to do as follows:

1. Fork, or otherwise create a repository for the changes / additions
2. Use `git submodule` to add the new repository to my project as a subfolder
3. Make changes within the submodule, or make changes to the created repository then update the submodule.

If you are as not as particular as I am about how you want the changes tracked, [ton's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19509544/165988) using Subtree works fine; the biggest difference is that all of the commits from the repository will be included in the repository's history.

Answer (score -1):

maybe, you should use subtree instead of submodule.

read following articles.

[Git - Subtree Merging](http://git-scm.com/book/ch6-7.html)

[Alternatives To Git Submodule: Git Subtree | Atlassian Blogs](http://blogs.atlassian.com/2013/05/alternatives-to-git-submodule-git-subtree/)

Comment: Subtree merging -chapter in Git book has nothing to do with the git feature called subtrees.

Comment: I tried this approach, but when I do this, the files appear to be treated as though they are part of the repository (instead of just referencing the other repository).